# Liquibase Implementation using jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, shared-libraries, liquibase

Is anyone having good links, video, blog or any online material for liquibase implementation using Jenkins pipeline (Shared Library).

Answer (score 0):

you can simply google this up. But here is what I found:

- https://piotrminkowski.com/2017/02/08/continuous-configuration-management-with-jenkins-and-liquibase/
- https://www.liquibase.org/blog/new-liquibase-runner-jenkins-plugin
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hIepgHK2teI
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LAfLsS0BTTQ
- https://www.liquibase.org/blog/new-liquibase-runner-jenkins-plugin